# Why angular mat-select call tiwce and change

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular Material mat-select as follows:

```
<mat-select formControlName="vehicle_id"[ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.vehicle_id.errors }" [disabled]="isVehicleSelect" (selectionChange)="changVehicle($event)">
     <mat-option *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicleList" [value]="vehicle.id">
                 {{vehicle.name}}
      </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
```

this is my ts file

```
  changVehicle(event) {
        var obj = {
            date: this.dateValue,
        }
     
        this.globalService.getAviliableSeates(obj).then(
            res => {
                console.log(res)
                this.aviliableSeats = res.data.seats;
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err)
            }
        )
    }
```

when i change dropdown value API two times I do not know why it is happening
here is screen shot of API Call

[image]

I used all these method already `(optionSelected)="changVehicle($event.option.value)"` `(ngModelChange)="changVehicle($event)"` `(selectionChange)="changVehicle($event)"` but nothing works any one have a solution
I am using angular 11 and material version 11.2.12

Comment: One is the preflight, not the actual request..

Comment: sorry i can get your point @MikeOne

Comment: Your code is fine, it only makes one request. The preflight is done by the browser (probably because it is a different domain).

Comment: then what is the solution for this problems

Comment: It’s not a problem, so it doesn’t need a solution. Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request